How can I select rows inside helm-projectile-find-file posframe
In my spacemacs on emacs 29.4, helm-projectile-find-file opens up a window titled posframe. It shows a list of files that I can narrow by typing normally, or I can move to a row that is already showing using C-j or C-k and press ENTER to open the file.
Is there a way I can select several rows and copy them to the kill-ring?
What I've tried already:
C-SPC allows me to mark rows, but I can't figure out how to copy them. y to yank is interpreted as an instruction to search for files whose name includes the letter y. I can't invoke functions using the meta key: SPC is interpreted as part of the search, M-x gives me an error: helm: Error: Trying to run helm within a running helm session
I can't view the posframe contents in a standard buffer using C-x C-b. That swaps to another posframe with the helm buffer listed, but pressing ENTER to visit it just takes me back to the original posframe list.
